# asp.net mvc using div or any such text control

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-3

I have been trying to use div element in the view in controller but i can't find the control.

This is what I've done in the view:

```
     <div id="z" style="display:none">
    <p id="af">Please enter your CustomerID.You cannot try to enter Products for a    different Customer </p>
    </div>
```

controller side:
The intellisense does not show me div id. and Findcontrol seems to be useless. So, I need to make the div element viewable. Can you please help me?

Answer (score 2):

I think you have major misunderstandings about how ASP.NET MVC works. There are no server controls. There is no ViewState, PostBacks and code behind contrary to what you might have the habit of using in classic WebForms. In ASP.NET MVC you write a Controller action which will receive the user request, manipulate the Model and pass a view model to the View for rendering.

I would recommend you checking out the following site and familiarize yourself with the basic notions by going through the tutorials: http://asp.net/mvc